# I want to refresh div content after form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So, I am using a `:remote => true` form with the paperclip gem to upload a photo. When I submit the form I just want to refresh the content of a div (which will now contain the uploaded photo).

Rails, however, insists on redirecting me to the path of the action used to process the photo submission. Additionally, there is the issue of actually refreshing the div.

I would like to do it with javascript, but there is no afterSubmit handler or anything. I can't figure out how to respond to the form submit with javascript either. I tried to do

```
def add_photo
  SomeModel.method_that_processes_and_saves(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

and placing the script in  `add_photo.js.erb`. However, the script is never sent (the browser is asking for html?) How can I get around this?? Its been frustrating me for a whole day now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_photo
  SomeModel.method_that_processes_and_saves(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{ render :update do |page|
      page << "$('#mydiv').html('bah-blah') "
  end
end
```

Or create `add_photo.js.erb` and write there any javascript you want.

It will work if you're submitting your form via AJAX (js request), that mean that you should add `:remote => true` option

Comment: The only thing is that Im using paperclip to upload files, and javascript can't touch the file system. What happens is that the browser requests an html response and ignores the remote. I'm currently trying to use an iframe to get around this, the question now is how to get controller to send the script back so it can be executed and affect the page itself.

Comment: there is a bunch of articles about uploading files via AJAX with Rails in the Internet

Comment: The upload itself works fine with the ifram, the main issue is the browser wanting to do something after the upload. I have managed to mimic a 'after submit' handler using a javascript timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of "afterSubmit" because the page has been replaced by the form submission.  The simplest way to tackle this is to handle the photo upload on the subsequent page. Ruby should give you the path.
Another approach is to use one of the many upload libraries to asynchronously do the upload and give you a "on complete" callback.   http://www.uploadify.com/ is a popular choice.